# Chart repositions itself to overlap text in a weird manner

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, charts

Here is my code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Data arrays.
    string[] seriesArray = { "Cats", "Dogs" };
    int[] pointsArray = { 1, 2 };

    // Set palette.
    this.chart1.Palette = ChartColorPalette.SeaGreen;

    // Set title.
    this.chart1.Titles.Add("Pets");

    // Add series.
    for (int i = 0; i < seriesArray.Length; i++)
    {
        // Add series.
        Series series = this.chart1.Series.Add(seriesArray[i]);

        // Add point.
        series.Points.Add(pointsArray[i]);
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.Titles[0].Position.Y = chart1.Titles[0].Position.Y + 1;
}
```

The problem i face is when i change the Location of the Title `Pets` is that the Chart redraws itself in a different way. I want to understand why does this happen and is there a way to work around this - since it brings the text on top of the chart and this happens only at the `first` time.

Here is what i mean:

[image]

How does adding `1` make such a huge difference in the chart?

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with DockingOffset instead of Position.Y

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.Titles[0].DockingOffset = chart1.Titles[0].DockingOffset + 1;
}
```

The problem with 'Position.Y' is that it starts with "auto" position, so the first time you add 1 to it, the compiler assign a value, redraws and then add 1.

Comment: Can you please explain further?

Comment: If not assigned, all the elements in the chart have a 'Auto' position value that fill the chart the best as they can. 

When you assign a position value to the 'chart's tittle', the tittle position change from 'auto' to a new value (according to his old position + 1 you add), all the elements in the chart with 'Auto' value re-arrange them-self w/o considering the tittle because it's not longer in 'auto'. Then, the chart is redraw and all elements in new positions.

DockingOffset add the offset properly because it use the initial 'auto' position as reference.

Answer (score 0):

> How does adding 1 make such a huge difference in the chart?

**First** that's because many or most `ChartElements` are positioned by **percentages**.

Some are by `Values`, given in doubles, other in `pixels`, but most are in **percentages** of their respective containers.

**Or**, initially set to **`auto`** and recalculated whenever necessary.

So if your `ChartArea` has a height of 80% and the `Chart`'s `Clientsize` is 500pixels the `ChartArea`'s height calculates to 400 pixels.

I don't know to what percentage the `Title.Position.Height` has been calculated in your chart, but if it is, say 4% then adding 1 makes it 5%, bringing it down from 20px to y=25px.

But wait, the difference you observe is a lot more than that! In fact the by far larger difference is the `Height & Top` of the `ChartArea`! Why is that?

**Secondly**, by messing with the `Chart's Title's Position` you have taken it out of the elements to consider when **auto-calculating** the available spaces, and with the `Title` 'gone' from that calculation, there suddenly is a lot more vertical space for the `ChartArea`. So is grows and even happens to overlap the `Title`.

How can you prevent that? Well you can prevent the changes from the calculation by taking the automatic out, maybe like this:

```
 RectangleF r = chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.ToRectangleF();
 chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position = new ElementPosition(r.X, r.Y, r.Width, r.Height);
```

Note that the other elements may be affected as well. So the `Legend` will also use the freed space at the top and move up.. (You can see that in your screenshot.) And since the spaces are no longer calculated automatically you will have to take care of some more issues, when some elements grow and need more space, like the axis labels or a `Legend`..

By the way, to restore a `ChartElement.Position` to `Auto` you need to set the values to `double.NaN`.